# sympy solveset fails to solve set of equations, while solve has no problem

Tags: python, sympy, equation

As recommended, I trying to use sympy.solveset instead of sympy.solve to solve a set of two equations.

```
from sympy import *
a1, a1dot, pa1, pa1dot, a2, a2dot, pa2, pa2dot, m, l = symbols('a1, a1dot, pa1, pa1dot, a2, a2dot, pa2, pa2dot, m, l')

eq1 = 2*m*l**2*a1dot + m*l**2*a2dot*cos(a1 - a2) - pa1 #equation one
eq2 = m*l**2*a2dot + m*l**2*a1dot*cos(a1 - a2) - pa2  #equation two
```

Using `solveset([eq1, eq2], (a1dot, a2dot))` gives me a "[eq1, eq1] is not a valid SymPy expression" error (eq1, eq2 are expanded to the full expressions they stand for in the error message).
But using `solve([eq1, eq2], (a1dot, a1dot))` works just fine and gives a correct result. However, I would like to follow the recommendation given in the SympPy documentation and use solveset instead. So what am I missinng?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation should be fixed to say that it is fine to use `solve` if you want.

You can't use `solveset` to solve a system of equation as it is for solving single univariate equations only. The newer solvers for systems of equations are `linsolve` and `nonlinsolve`. Either of those will work for this system but there is also nothing wrong with using `solve`:

```
In [2]: solve([eq1, eq2], [a1dot, a2dot])
Out[2]: 
⎧      -pa₁ + pa₂⋅cos(a₁ - a₂)          pa₁⋅cos(a₁ - a₂) - 2⋅pa₂ ⎫
⎪a1̇: ───────────────────────────, a2̇: ───────────────────────────⎪
⎨     2      2               2         2      2               2  ⎬
⎪    l ⋅m⋅cos (a₁ - a₂) - 2⋅l ⋅m      l ⋅m⋅cos (a₁ - a₂) - 2⋅l ⋅m⎪
⎩                                                                ⎭

In [3]: linsolve([eq1, eq2], [a1dot, a2dot])
Out[3]: 
⎧⎛  -pa₁ + pa₂⋅cos(a₁ - a₂)      pa₁⋅cos(a₁ - a₂) - 2⋅pa₂ ⎞⎫
⎪⎜───────────────────────────, ───────────────────────────⎟⎪
⎨⎜ 2      2               2     2      2               2  ⎟⎬
⎪⎝l ⋅m⋅cos (a₁ - a₂) - 2⋅l ⋅m  l ⋅m⋅cos (a₁ - a₂) - 2⋅l ⋅m⎠⎪
⎩                                                          ⎭

In [4]: nonlinsolve([eq1, eq2], [a1dot, a2dot])
Out[4]: 
⎧⎛-pa₁ + pa₂⋅cos(a₁ - a₂)   pa₁⋅cos(a₁ - a₂) - 2⋅pa₂⎞⎫
⎪⎜────────────────────────, ────────────────────────⎟⎪
⎨⎜ 2   ⎛   2             ⎞   2   ⎛   2             ⎞⎟⎬
⎪⎝l ⋅m⋅⎝cos (a₁ - a₂) - 2⎠  l ⋅m⋅⎝cos (a₁ - a₂) - 2⎠⎠⎪
⎩                                                    ⎭
```